# Applying collect() to a Apache Spark structured streaming Dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, streaming

I'm new to Apache Spark and currently working on a Structured Streaming pipeline. In the middle of the data processing I need to do a bit of finnicky manipulation that requires that *all* of the data (so far) is present. The amount of data has been heavily reduced at this point in the pipeline and performing a `.collect()`-like action will not be a bottleneck. The operation I need to perform is basically putting all remaining elements in a HashSet and doing a series of tricky existence checks. After this, I need to "re-enter" the streaming-pipeline to perform various writes to csv-files.

However, attempting to perform `collect()` on a streaming pipeline understandably results in an error message. Below is a barebones (and stupid) example that illustrates my problem:

```
// imports ...

val spark = SparkSession.builder
                        .appName("StructuredNetworkWordCount")
                        .getOrCreate()
val lines = spark.readStream
                 .format("socket")
                 .option("host", "localhost")
                 .option("port", 4444)
                 .load()

import spark.implicits._

// Split the lines into words
val words = lines.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))

// Won't work in a streaming context
val wordList = words.collectAsList()

// Perform some operations on the collected() data
val numWords = wordList.size
val doubledNum = numWords * 2

// Somehow output doubledNum
val query = wordCounts.writeStream
                      .outputMode("complete")
                      .format("console")
                      .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

As I said, this will definitely not work, but illustrates my problem. I need to perform a `collect()`-like action *in the middle of every microbatch* in order to have simultaneous access to all data that is left. How would I go about doing this? Are accumulators the only way to access all the cumulative data in all partitions in the middle of a streaming pipeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all spark structure streaming return DataFrame object and it does not support map and flatMap methods, so you can use foreach method where you can manipulate input stream data and use counter to count all required elements.